# Why does App Engine (standard enviorment) shut down instances even if it had a request 2 minutes before?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I have an app in App Engine Standard Environment, with Django installed. The scaling is automatic.

As I understand (by Stackoverflow responses) when you have automatic scaling, if an instance doesn't receive a request in 10 minutes, App Engine turns off the instance.

That's why I created a job in Cloud Scheduler, so every 10 minutes it makes a request to my instance. However in several occasions I have seen this:

[image: Logging]

As it can be seen, Cloud Scheduler made a request at 8:50, and two minutes later, the instance was shut down, then 10 minutes later, it had to start again, taking almost 3 seconds.

This is my **app.yaml**:

```
# [START django_app]
runtime: python37
handlers:
# This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's
# static directory.
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
# This handler routes all requests not caught above to the main app. 
# It is required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted 
# (along with the entire handlers section) when there are no static 
# files defined.
- url: /.*
  script: auto
  secure: always
# [END django_app]
```

**Why does this happen?**

Comment: Since the auto scaling behavior of App Engine is tightly related to its configuration can you please share your app.yaml?

Comment: @Chris32 I just added the app.yaml

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the additional information.

If you want to manage the autoscaling properties of your application to keep an instance alive without any traffic incoming for 10 minutes you can use the [basic scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#automatic_scaling) properties to set an idle timeout for your instances.

i.e. you can add this to your app.yaml

```
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 2
  idle_timeout: 10m
```